# Python: Interpolate array of unknown size into string

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python, I'm trying to add elements from an array into a string using "%s".

However, at compile time, the size of the array, and the string i'm interpolating into, are unknown. The idea is that i'm making a madlibs type script which pulls the text from a separate file.

Current code:

```
from sys import argv

script, input = argv

infile = open(input)

madlibs = eval(infile.readline())
words = []

for word in madlibs:
    words.append(raw_input("Give me a %s: " % word))

print infile.read() % words
```

So, the first line of the input file contains the madlib questions, and the subsequent text has the story. Here is the example input file i'm using:

```
["noun", "verb", "verb", "noun"]
There once was a %s named Bill.
He liked to %s all the time.
But he did it too much, and his girlfriend got mad.
She then decided to %s him to get back at him.
He died. It's a sad story.
They buried him. And on his tombstone, they placed a %s.
```

So, in an ideal world,

```
print infile.read() % words
```

would work, as it would just interpolate the elements in "words" into the string pulled from the file.

However, it doesn't, and i'm out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: You should be using `ast.literal_eval` rather than `eval` since the input is untrusted, and what you want is a Python literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `words` is a tuple:

```
print(infile.read() % tuple(words))
```

By the way, a MadLib sometimes repeats the same supplied word. It would therefore be easier to make `words` a `dict` instead of `list`. You could then do something like this:

```
words = {
    'man' : 'Bill',
    'store' : 'bar',
    'drink' : 'beer',
    'owner' : 'bartender',
    'action' : 'drink',
    }

text = '''
{man} walks into a {store} and orders a {drink}.
The {owner} asks {man} what he would like to {action}
'''

print(text.format(**words))
```

which yields

```
Bill walks into a bar and orders a beer.
The bartender asks Bill what he would like to drink
```

Comment: +1 This is what came into my mind when I saw the question! :)

Comment: or `words = tuple(raw_input("Give me a %s: " % word) for word in madlibs)`.

Comment: wow, this is exactly what i needed. thanks so much!
so why does the tuple work, but not the list? i understand that a tuple in immutable, but why does it make a difference here?

Comment: @Ghatokachan It's mandated by the specification.  Given `format % values`, "[If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple object. Otherwise, values must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary)](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)".

Answer (score 1):

"it doesn't" how?  Include an error message.  The likely problem is you need a tuple not a list:

```
>>> print "%s %s %s %s" % ['This','is','a','test']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> print "%s %s %s %s" % ('This','is','a','test')
This is a test
>>> print "%s %s %s %s" % tuple(['This','is','a','test'])
This is a test
```